# MS-Access Add New record to a selected field

Tags: ms-access

How would i make it so that instead of having my Project selected and inserting new records for that project (Select > Add Item > Save record > select > etc) id like it so that once the record is selected i dont have to keep going back and selecting it to add new records to that project.

here is a picture of the proccess

[image]

Comment: What code is attached to your "Add New item" command button?

Comment: At the minute it is just an add new record event. made in the wizard

Comment: Actually I'll rephrase the question, you have 2 Add New Item buttons, I would have assumed that the bottom one in the Item description box, would only add a "sub item" description and not clear out the whole form? 

Without seeing the code behind it, it is very difficult to guess.

Comment: sorry my fault, they are just copies of each other. if can send you an example of the system if you'd like?

Comment: basically i want to add multiple items without it having to requery the Project ID after each record is made and saved

Comment: It's certainly possible. Can you paste the code that the button does, or is it literally `docmd.gotorecord acNew`

Comment: yes literally just an event GoToRecord. there must be a way of keeping the Project ID and Client Name Populated when a new record is made?

Comment: While there are ways to do what you want with a bound form, I find that data entry is much better accomplished with unbound forms. Not only do you have full control of what information remains put when a new record is added, but you can perform data validation before creating records, so you don't end up with a lot of trash/half finished records.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. One route is to change the default value for the controls you want to stay the same, after they have been updated.

Edit.

In the After Update event of the Yourfield put code like this:

```
Me.YourControl.Tag = Me.YourControl.Value
```

In the On Enter Event of the same field put code like this:

```
If Not Me.NewRecord Then Exit Sub
If Not (IsNull(Me.YourControl.Tag) Or Me.YourControl.Tag = "") Then
   Me.YourControl.Value = Me.YourControl.Tag
End If
```

Comment: Unfortunately it comes up with #Name? when new record is added

Comment: See the edit, it's a more complicated method but more robust.

Comment: Microsoft Access cant find the field "Project_ID" referred to in your expression. runtime error message. although that is the correct field name

Comment: Yeah they are the same Both are Project ID and Client Name (Project_ID, Client_Name)

Comment: I would change the control names to txtProjectID and txtClientName. You then know explicitly what you are referring to on the form. E.g. The controls and not the underlying field values.

Comment: ive changed the names, unfortunately it doesn't seem to work

Comment: So what error are you now getting? Can you edit your post to show the current code, and the error message ?